# Cannot convert Greek lowercase to uppercase without accents in LuaLaTeX. How can I?

Tags: luatex, polyglossia, accents, greek, uppercase

Please consider the following `LuaLaTeX` compilable code. It supposes to convert a sentence written in lowercase Greek to UPPERCASE, but with no accents. It converts to uppercase but the accents are still there in capital letters. Furthermore, it uses two different ways, both failing. Any suggestions appreciated.

[image]

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={180mm,257mm},left=15mm,top=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase, Script=Greek}
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{greek}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\begin{document}
    Μικρό Κείμενο για τον έλεγχο της μετατροπής των πεζών σε κεφαλαία

    \MakeUppercase{Μικρό Κείμενο για τον έλεγχο της μετατροπής των πεζών σε κεφαλαία}

    \let\acctonos\relax\MakeUppercase{Μικρό Κείμενο για τον έλεγχο της μετατροπής των πεζών σε κεφαλαία}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Mico.I can use both `babel` and `polyglossia`. I will use `babel` now. Thank you for the notice. I'm just wondering what happened because some days before I didn't had this problem.

Comment: It looks like there’s a simpler solution posted already, but if you can’t use Babel, it would be possible to normalize the input to NFD form, remove the combining accents, and then uppercase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changes to the way case mappings are handled make the system locale-aware. At present, this is set up to 'auto-detect' locale from `babel` but not `polyglossia`: regrettably, there is not yet a single common interface for accessing this data. One can give the locale manually

```
\MakeUppercase[locale = el]{...}
```

but this is intended for more *ad hoc* situations. You can add in the functionality for `polyglossia`, but this does rely on internal data structures:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={180mm,257mm},left=15mm,top=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase, Script=Greek}\defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Scale=1.1}
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}%\setsansfont{FiraSans}\setmonofont{Consolas}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{greek}\setotherlanguage{english}
\makeatletter
\protected\def\@@text@case@aux@{\edef\reserved@a{\csuse{bcp47id}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    Μικρό Κείμενο για τον έλεγχο της μετατροπής των πεζών σε κεφαλαία
    \MakeUppercase{Μικρό Κείμενο για τον έλεγχο της μετατροπής των πεζών σε κεφαλαία}
    \let\acctonos\relax\MakeUppercase{Μικρό Κείμενο για τον έλεγχο της μετατροπής των πεζών σε κεφαλαία}
    
\end{document}
```

(There is currently a bug in `expl3` which means you need

```latex
\def\@@text@case@aux@@#1-#2\stop{#1}
\protected\def\@@text@case@aux@{%
  \edef\reserved@a{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
    \@@text@case@aux@@\csname bcp47id\endcsname-\stop
  }%
}
```

but this will be fixed by tomorrow.)

Comment: Very pleased for that! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

If you can use [babel](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel) instead of [polyglossia](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/polyglossia), the problem you've encountered goes away on its own, without further ado.

[image]

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={180mm,257mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Script=Greek} % is this needed?
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text} % select a suitable text font

%\usepackage{polyglossia}\setdefaultlanguage{greek}\setotherlanguage{english}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\begin{document}
Μικρό Κείμενο για τον έλεγχο της μετατροπής των πεζών σε κεφαλαία

\MakeUppercase{Μικρό Κείμενο για τον έλεγχο της μετατροπής των πεζών σε κεφαλαία}

\let\acctonos\relax
\MakeUppercase{Μικρό Κείμενο για τον έλεγχο της μετατροπής των πεζών σε κεφαλαία} 
\end{document}
```